# How to remove newlines from an ip a s output?

Tags: bash, sed

INPUT ("ip a s" command)

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether e3:1c:12:f3:5a:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 1.2.3.4/24 brd 1.2.3.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::e61f:13ff:fef3:5a34/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

OUTPUT:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo inet6 ::1/128 scope host valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000 link/ether e3:1c:12:f3:5a:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff inet 1.2.3.4/24 brd 1.2.3.255 scope global eth0 inet6 fe80::e61f:13ff:fef3:5a34/64 scope link valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Question:** how can I remove the new lines as in the INPUT/OUTPUT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ugly solution before perl/sed expert

```
 ip a s| awk 'BEGIN { s=0 ; } /^[^\t ]/ {if (s>0) printf "\n" ; s++ ; } {printf " %s",$0;} END { printf "\n" ;}'
```

basically

```
 BEGIN { s=0 ; }
```

counter for line

```
 /^[^\t ]/ {if (s>0) printf "\n" ; s++ ; }
```

if line begin with non blank, and not forst, issue a newline

```
 {printf " %s",$0;}
```

copy line with out newline

```
  END { printf "\n" ;}
```

at the end, use a new line.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-o`/`-oneline` option. This is exactly what it's for.

```
# ip -o addr show
1: lo    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
1: lo    inet6 ::1/128 scope host \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlan0    inet 192.168.0.24/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global wlan0\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlan0    inet6 fe80::c685:8ff:fe80:dd06/64 scope link \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0    inet 172.17.42.1/16 scope global docker0\       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0    inet6 fe80::5484:7aff:fefe:9799/64 scope link \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
23: veth3d95    inet6 fe80::8429:16ff:fed6:beb3/64 scope link \       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `perl`:

```
$ ip a s | perl -00pe 's/\n *(?![0-9])/ /g'
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN  link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever inet6 ::1/128 scope host  valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000 link/ether f4:6d:04:11:43:fc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer `sed` you could try **[this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489410/how-to-join-a-line-with-a-pattern-with-the-next-line-with-sed)**, which also has a nice explanation:

You can use `^[[:digit:]]` because of the output of `ip`.

```
ip addr show | sed -e '/^[[:digit:]]/bpp' -e 'H;$bpp' -e 'd' -e ':pp' -e 'x;/^$/d;s/\n/ /g'
```