# How to join a line with a pattern with the next line with sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed, join

I can't find this case in the board, so I'm asking the question.

This is input file:

```
module  
x(a,b,c)  
module  
y(d,e,f,  
g,h,i)  
module  
z(j,k,l)
```

And output file should be:

```
module x(a,b,c)  
module y(d,e,f,  
g,h,i)  
module z(j,k,l)
```

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

What you want to do is to join the `module` lines with the next line.

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed '/^module/N;s/\n//' file
module  x(a,b,c)
module  y(d,e,f,
g,h,i)
module  z(j,k,l)
```

This is with your data copied and pasted as is, with spaces at the end of each line.

The `sed` command will print each line as it is read, but when it encounters a line that starts with the string `module`, it appends the next line with an embedded newline character in-between (this is what `N` does).  We remove that newline character with a substitution before the result is printed.

If your data has no spaces at the end of the lines, use

```
$ sed '/^module/N;s/\n/ /' file
module x(a,b,c)
module y(d,e,f,
g,h,i)
module z(j,k,l)
```

---

Just in case you'd want this (assuming no spaces at end of input lines):

```
$ sed -e '/^module/bpp' -e 'H;$bpp' -e 'd' \
      -e ':pp' -e 'x;/^$/d;s/\n/ /g' file
module x(a,b,c)
module y(d,e,f, g,h,i)
module z(j,k,l)
```

Annotated `sed` script:

```
/^module/ b print_previous; # print previous record
H;                          # append this line to hold space
$         b print_previous; # print previous (last) record
d;                          # end processing this line

:print_previous;            # prints a record accumulated in the hold space
x;                          # swap in the hold space
/^$/ d;                     # if line is empty, delete it
s/\n/ /g;                   # replace embedded newlines by spaces
                            # (implicit print)
```

---

Bonus `ed` content:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' 'g/^module/ j' ,p Q | ed -s file
module  x(a,b,c)
module  y(d,e,f,
g,h,i)
module  z(j,k,l)
```

The above joins any line starting with the string `module` with its next line.

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' 'v/^module/ -,.j' ,p Q | ed -s file
module  x(a,b,c)
module  y(d,e,f,  g,h,i)
module  z(j,k,l)
```

The above joins any line *not* starting with the string `module` with its *previous* line.

Answer (score 4):

Using awk:

```
~ awk '/^module/ {l = $0; getline; printf "%s", l} 1' input-file
module  x(a,b,c)
module  y(d,e,f,
g,h,i)
module  z(j,k,l)
```

For each line that starts with `module`, save the line in `l`, move to the next line (`getline`), and print the saved line without a newline. Then print every line.

Answer (score 1):

Another option: create an `ed` script!

This starts by pre-counting the number of joins that are required; it then generates that number of `ed` search & join commands and pipes them, along with a save & quit at the end, into `ed`:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=$(grep -c '^module *$' input)
{
  for((i=1; i <= n; i++))
  do
    printf '/^module *$/\n.,+1j\n'
  done
  echo w
  echo q
} | ed -s input >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne '/^module/ ?? (print "$_\t"; put get) !! .put;'  file
```

OR:

```
~$ raku -ne '/^module/ ?? (put join "\t", $_, lines[0]) !! .put;' file
```

The Raku answer above is similar to the excellent `awk` answer by @muru. In Raku the ternary operator is spelled **Test** `??` **True** `!!` **False**. The `-ne` flags read the file linewise without autoprinting.

If the line starts with `module` it is `print`ed, followed by a `\t` tab (this can be replaced with any column separator). Then (in the first example) the code instructs to `get` the next line and `put` it. In the second example you print the `$_` topic variable, and take the next line `line[0]` join on `\t` and out`put` it. If no match to `module` (i.e. "False"), the line is simply out`put`.

Sample Input (line-endings cleaned up):

```
module
x(a,b,c)
module
y(d,e,f,
g,h,i)
module
z(j,k,l)
```

Sample Output (tab-separated columns):

```
module  x(a,b,c)
module  y(d,e,f,
g,h,i)
module  z(j,k,l)
```

Note the OP's input text contains trailing whitespace, so while using that raw input may be fine, other example text files that are to be concatenated might not contain trailing whitespace, in which case the "columns" will run-together. Hence the use of `\t` above to space columns.

https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org