# How to make awk print 3 items in line, The last value if is empty?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have the following text:

```
Name= Garen
Class= 9C
School= US
Name= Lulu
Class= 4A
Name= Kata
Class= 10D
School= UK
```

I got the awk cmd below:

```
awk '$Name ~/Name/ {printf $0;} $Class ~/Class/ {printf $0;} $School ~/School/ {print $0;} ' file.txt
```

But it outputs in a new line. Like this:

```
Name= Garen Class= 9C School= US
Name= Lulu Class= 4A Name= Kata Class= 10D School= UK
```

I want it to output like this :

```
Name= Garen ,Class= 9C ,School= US
Name= Lulu , Class= 4A ,
Name= Kata ,Class= 10D ,School= UK
```

---

if it falls into a situation :

```
Name= Garen
Class= 9C
Last Name= Wilson 
School= US

Name= Lulu
Class= 4A
Last Name= Miller

Name= Kata
Class= 10D
School= UK
Last Name= Thomas
```

and print:

```
Name= Garen,Class= 9C,School= US

Name= Lulu,Class= 4A

Name= Kata,Class= 10D,School= UK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' '/^Name/ { if (line != "") print line; line = $0; next } { line = line OFS $0 } END { if (line != "") print line }' file
Name= Garen,Class= 9C,School= US
Name= Lulu,Class= 4A
Name= Kata,Class= 10D,School= UK
```

With the updated input in the question, this produces

```
Name= Garen,Class= 9C,Last Name= Wilson ,School= US,
Name= Lulu,Class= 4A,Last Name= Miller,
Name= Kata,Class= 10D,School= UK,Last Name= Thomas
```

If you want to delete the `Last Name` bit, ignore it explicitly in the `awk` code:

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' '/^Last Name/ { next } /^Name/ { if (line != "") print line; line = $0; next } { line = line OFS $0 } END { if (line != "") print line }' file
Name= Garen,Class= 9C,School= US,
Name= Lulu,Class= 4A,
Name= Kata,Class= 10D,School= UK
```

The `awk` code, as a freestanding `awk` program with comments:

```
BEGIN {
    # Set output field separator to a comma.
    # This can also be done with -v OFS="," on the command line.

    OFS = ","
}

/^Last Name/ {
    # Ignore these lines
    next
}

/^Name/ {
    # A line starts with "Name".
    # Print the accumulated line and reset the line variable.
    # Continue immediately with next line of input.

    if (line != "")
        print line

    line = $0
    next
}

{
    # Accumulate lines in the line variable.
    # Delimit each input data with OFS (a comma).

    line = line OFS $0
}

END {
    # Print the last accumulated line.

    if (line != "")
        print line
}
```

---

With `sed` (this is an almost identical solution [from an answer to another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489410))

```
/^Last Name/ d;             # ignore these lines
/^Name/ b print_previous;   # print previous record
H;                          # append this line to hold space
$       b print_previous;   # print previous (last) record
d;                          # end processing this line

:print_previous;            # prints a record accumulated in the hold space
x;                          # swap in the hold space
/^$/ d;                     # if line is empty, delete it
s/\n/,/g;                   # replace embedded newlines by commas
                            # (implicit print)
```

Running it:

```
$ sed -f script.sed file
Name= Garen,Class= 9C,School= US
Name= Lulu,Class= 4A
Name= Kata,Class= 10D,School= UK
```

Comment: I just updated question .

Comment: @thinhluu I still can't see what's wrong. Sorry. Is it that the `Last Name` should be removed?

Comment: I added variable Last Name but i wanna print do not take Last Name .

Comment: @thinhluu This is what my latest modifications to the answer does.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> awk '$Name ~/Name/ {printf $0;} $Class ~/Class/ {printf $0;} $School ~/School/ {print $0;} ' file.txt
> ```

All of `$Name`, `$Class` and `$School` will act exactly as `$0`, because the `Name`, `Class` and `School` variables are not defined and in `awk` any undefined variable has the numeric value of `0` and (at least with `mawk` and `gawk`) the `$` operator will simply convert its argument to a number. Other `awk` implementations may bail out with an error (the behavior is unspecified by the standard).

Try this instead:

```
awk -F ' *= *' '$1~/^(Name|Class|School)$/{
       if($1 in a){ for(i in a) delete a[i]; comma = ""; printf ORS }
       printf "%s%s= %s", comma, $1, $2; a[$1] = comma = ", "
     }
     END{if(comma) printf ORS}
' file.txt

Name= Garen, Class= 9C, School= US
Name= Lulu, Class= 4A
Name= Kata, Class= 10D, School= UK
```

The example above tries hard to group key/value tuples no matter what order they're in, and be general (it will work *the same* on the 1st sample input if the `$1~/.../` pattern is removed); but if you know that `Name` is always first and always present, then everything is much easier:

```
awk '/^Name=/{printf "%s%s", nl, $0; nl=ORS}
     /^(Class|School)=/{printf ", %s", $0}
     END{if(nl) printf ORS}' /tmp/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` for this, with the following one-liner, as follow:

```
awk -F\< '/Name=/ {LGT=length($2);printf("\n%s,",substr($2,6,LGT))};
/Class=/ {LGT=length($2);printf(" %s,",substr($2,6,LGT))}; 
/School=/ {LGT=length($2);printf(" %s",substr($2,6,LGT))};
END {printf("\n") }' file.txt
```

This solution will print records (i.e. lines in your original `file.txt` file) in the order in which they appear in `file.txt`. I added it because it is a (simple) example of how to parse and manipulate strings with `awk`.

As in previous answers, file.txt contains:

```
<text>Name= Garen</text>
<text>Class= 9C</text>
<text>School= US</text>
<text>Name= Lulu</text>
<text>Class= 4A</text>
<text>Name= Kata</text>
<text>Class= 10D</text>
<text>School= UK</text>
```

Output is:

```
Name= Garen, Class= 9C, School= US
Name= Lulu, Class= 4A
Name= Kata, Class= 10D, School= UK
```