# How to selectively join lines starting with a pattern

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed, join

This post may be looked upon as a [followup to a previous post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489410/how-to-join-a-line-with-a-pattern-with-the-next-line-with-sed).

This is input file:

```
module ABC   
x(a,b,c)  
module DEFG  
y(d,e,f,  
g,h,i)  
module HIJKL  
z(j,k,l)
```

And output file should be:

```
module ABC x(a,b,c)  
module DEFG y(d,e,f,  
g,h,i)  
module HIJKL z(j,k,l)
```

---

I tried using asterisk as a wildcard character in the solutions provided in the [referenced post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489410/how-to-join-a-line-with-a-pattern-with-the-next-line-with-sed) but it did not work as expected.

---

**Addendum**
Upon closer examination I found out that indeed the solutions provided earlier work for me as well (as pointed out by @steeldriver).  The problem was that the file originated from a DOS/Windows platform and there was an unexpected `^M` character that got inserted into the output, which was messing up down-the-line processing for me.  I have now run dos2unix on the input file and the problem has gone away (i.e. the previous solutions work for me as well).

I am recommending that this post be closed as duplicate.

Comment: Why do you need a "wildcard character"? what exactly is unsatisfactory about the previous answers such as `sed '/^module/N;s/\n//'`?

Comment: Indeed the solutions provided earlier work for me as well (as pointed out by @steeldriver). Kindly see the addendum to my post regarding why I missed out on that.  I am recommending that this post be closed as duplicate.

Comment: Closed the question as a duplicate of the question indicated, on request from the user (which makes sense to me too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using **awk** :

```
awk '{if ($0 ~ /^module/) {ORS=""}  else {ORS="\r\n"} ; print}'
```